# How JNI works on the memory level

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, jnienv

I have a java file which loads .so files and prints the result coming from .so file. I don't have a source code for my .so file. Can anyone tell how in the memory structure .so results are loaded and from where this Java class is reading the results generated by .so and printing them out??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If u have any code that is already written in native language and reluctant about changing it but you would want to use native calls in your java codes and not to rewrite entirely everything java. JNI comes in handy. it converts all your platform specific implementations to platform independent. Performance- and platform-sensitive API implementations in the standard library allows all Java applications to access this functionality. 
the library files .so are converted in such a manner.

JNIEnv contains all types of conversion from a native data types to the java data types. it also supports suitable implementations for native method calls, signals are also handled by the JVM.

Java being platform independent native processss specific to a hardware and operating system platform are all made platform independent by mapping native data types and method calls to java. JNI performs the above using the library files example .so or .a files

For JNI mapping u can refer the below link 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/types.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It does help. And yes I have a code written in Java which loads libSSM.so which calculates the CPU usage value. This Java program prints the values of CPU usage coming from .so file on an android application. Ofcourse, Java must be reading these values from somewhere in the memory, so was wondering where in the memory structure values coming from .so files are stored.

Answer (score 0):

Your .so have a JNI glue class that binds all your Java native methods (public native void x();) with compiled native code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming it uses JNI, otherwise I have no idea how its working.  If it uses JNI, then it actually creates Java objects on the Java heap in the .so, using the JNI libraries.  Look for functions marked "native", these functions map directly to functions in the so that are called when th Java code whats to run something in the library.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, it uses JNI, and loads using System.LoadLibrary(.so), but did not know about the function mapping. The Java program uses libSSM.so to monitor the CPU usage and print the result on the android app. So was wondering from where does the MainActivity.java reads the value which comes from compiled C++ code in the memory structure.

Answer (score 0):

The [Droidfish Android chess game](https://github.com/peterosterlund2/droidfish) is written in `Java`. But its underlying chess engine [Stockfish](https://github.com/official-stockfish/Stockfish) is written in `C++`. At first, I thought there was a `JNI` layer that connects these two but there isn't. The C++ stockfish executable is launched, and `Java` and `C++` communicates via [stream](https://github.com/peterosterlund2/droidfish/blob/master/DroidFishApp/src/main/java/org/petero/droidfish/engine/ExternalEngine.java#L118-L139).

You can launch the C++ stockfish and play with this engine in the command line, no graphical interfaces.

In your question, your native `.so` library is printing something to `stdout/stderr` and you want to read these outputs in Java?